# Magento 2 cache warmer for all customer groups

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache, cache-warmer

I am creating cache warmer extension for Magento 2.

The main logic that I am using is: A cronjob will get all the URLs from `url_rewrite` table and crawl every URL using `curl calls`.

The issue that I am facing is, Magento creates separate cache for all the customer groups, and I need to crawl all the pages along with all the groups.

My question is, how can I crawl a page using `curl` by using **General group** and **Not Loggedin** group?

Comment: Could you please share code base for this implementation "A cronjob will get all the URLs from url_rewrite table and crawl every URL using curl calls."?